# Сменить заставку homescreen android из приложения.

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток, такой вопрос: Возможно ли изменить заставку homescreen на android из приложения, не из настроек? Если да, то каким образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053919/programmatically-set-android-phones-background)

В манифесте прописываете.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER">
```

Код ниже устанавливает картинку фоном рабочего стола(ака homescreen).

```
        Button buttonSetWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set);
        ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        imagePreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);

        buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.five);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }});
```